# What is the rpc IP address?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, rinkeby, rpc, iot

I've only begun with blockchain(rinkeby-testnet) and IOT. I use nodemcu (ARDUINO IDE) and mist. What should the rpc-ip address be? Do I have to establish an ethereum node in order to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right.

[Command Line Options](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options)：

> ...
>
> API AND CONSOLE OPTIONS:
>
> --rpc                  Enable the HTTP-RPC server
>
> --rpcaddr value        HTTP-RPC server listening interface (default: "localhost")
>
> --rpcport value        HTTP-RPC server listening port (default: 8545)
>
> --rpcapi value         API's offered over the HTTP-RPC interface
>
> ...